# npm ERR! [nodegit] ERROR - finished with error code: 1 (wsl)

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I get this error when I run npm i in wsl, I don't know how to fix it:

```
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/server/RbxJs2016-main/node_modules/nodegit
npm ERR! gyp
npm ERR! ERR! node -v v17.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.2.0
npm ERR! gyp
npm ERR! ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp
npm ERR! ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp
npm ERR! ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/home/server/RbxJs2016-main/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/nodegit.node --module_name=nodegit --module_path=/home/server/RbxJs2016-main/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v102' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/server/RbxJs2016-main/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1062:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp
npm ERR! ERR! System Linux 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/server/RbxJs2016-main/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/server/RbxJs2016-main/node_modules/nodegit
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v17.0.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.9
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR!
npm ERR! not ok
npm ERR! [nodegit] ERROR - Could not finish install
npm ERR! [nodegit] ERROR - finished with error code: 1
```

I've tried several things but it won't work!
Im using WSL Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and node 16.19.0
the problem seems to come from node-gyp but I don't know how to fix it